# Creating Search engine friendly URLS using marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, single-page-application

I am creating single page application using marionette.js.My url looks like when user clicks on privacy  is `http://192.168.1.4:8080/Client_bit/index.html#privacy` I am trying to make SEO freindly urls like `http://192.168.1.4:8080/Client_bit/index.html/privacy` is it possible with marionette.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and it's done the same way as Backbone: you simply start the router with `pushState: true` (see http://backbonejs.org/#History-start)

However, make sure your webserver returns a valid page for **EVERY** URL your marionette app generates, or pushState won't work...

Comment: Don't know, I've never used it.

Comment: @ David Sulc Thanks. I read your book. It help me lot to learn marionette.